# getSelectedIndex() returning object

Tags: java, vector, actionlistener

Why do I get this error? Shouldn't `getSelectedIndex()` return an `int`?

```
ConsoleBuy.java:255: error: incompatible types
co = vt6.get(lConSelected.getSelectedIndex());
            ^
required: int
found:    Object
```

Its working when I remove an item from another vector.

```
vt3.remove(lConSelected.getSelectedIndex());
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [`getSelectedIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) returns an `int`, and the [`get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) method will return an `Object` from your `List`.  (Presumably, `vt6` is some kind of Collection and `lConSelected` is some Swing component.)

By the looks of it, it seems like your `co` variable is an `int` and you're trying to put an `Object` into it.